# Gitlab CI Pip command not found for image python3.10.3-bullseye

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
## PRE-CHECK ##
pre-check:
  stage: pre-check
  image: python:3.10.3-bullseye
  script:
#    - ls /usr/local/bin
#    - ls /usr/bin
    - pip install poetry
    - pip install pre-commit
    - cd ./backend
    - poetry install --no-root
    - pre-commit run --all-files

  only:
    changes:
      - '**/*.py'
```

This is the configuration for the CI stage. but when running the scripts its says *bash: line 138: pip: command not found
*
I cant even run python3.10 -m pip .  Returns error Python3.10 does not have a module pip

I debugged user/local/bin . this folder is empty

I was expecting that i could installl potery and precommit then run the check

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there are different types of executors in gitlab runner. The one I was using called shell executor. But my configuration was for docker executor.
running `gitlab-runner exec docker <stage-name>` solved the probelm .